# Is there any way to keep compressed file extension using "SevenZip.LzmaAlone" class compression?

Tags: java, compression, 7zip, lzma

I'm working on big files compression using Java. It's mandatory (for me) to compress my files unto 7z files (LZMA compression).

To do that, I'm using the [7z Java SKD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/). I'm calling the Decoder.code(...) method and everything's working fine. I get a compressed 7z file from my original one. The only problem is that when I manually extrat it, I get an extension-less file while it should be a ".xml" file ...

Anyone's got an idea on how to keep my original file's extension even through the 7z archive ?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the extensions are gone? Maybe you use Windows and the folder is set up to hide file extenstions ;)

Comment: No, extensions are shown in my explorer. And even if they were hidden, Windows would recognize it as archives (7z) and it doesn't. (These are just extension-less files ...)